Invertible associated matrix of a linear transformation implies invertible transformation
Let $V$ and $W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces with ordered bases $\beta$ and $\gamma$ respectively. Let $T:V\to W$ linear. Then $T$ is invertible if and only if $[T]^{\gamma}_{\beta}$ is invertible. Furthermore, $[T^{-1}]^{\beta}_{\gamma}=([T]^{\gamma}_{\beta})^{-1}$
I'm reading Linear Algebra by Friedberg and I'm asked to justify each step of the next proof. My doubts are on the second implication: If $[T]^{\gamma}_{\beta}$ is invertible, then $T$ is invertible.
We have that $[T]^{\gamma}_{\beta}$ is invertible, then by definition, there exists $B\in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb K)$ such that $AB=BA=I_n$. then, we know for a theorem that there exists a unique linear transformation $U\in \mathcal L(W,V)$ such that:
$U(w_j)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} B_{ij}v_i, \text{for} j=1,2,\dots ,n$
where $\gamma=\{w_1,w_2,\dots ,w_n\}$ and $\beta=\{v_1,v_2,\dots ,v_n\}$. So that would be a linear combination of $v\in V$, but why can we consider the elements in $B$?, knowing by the theorem, that $U(w_j)=v_j$, we assign exactly one vector of $\gamma$ to a vetor not precisely in $\beta$?
And it follows for the definition of $U$: we obtain the associated matrix, wich is $[U]^{\beta}_{\gamma}=B$. What is left, is to show that $U=T^{-1}$
Can you give me a clue? thanks!

$[U \circ T]\beta^\beta = [U]\gamma^\beta [T]_\beta^\gamma = BA = I_n$, so $U \circ T$ is the identity on $V$ (why?). Similarly, $T \circ U$ is the identity on $W$. Thus, $T$ is invertible.

thanks! That's the last part. But what can you say about the $B_{ij}$ for representing vectors in $V$?

@Roma_Rayado how you got $U(w_j)=v_j$?

@Roma_Rayado $$U(w_j)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} B_{ij}v_j, \forall j=1,2,\dots ,n$$ is it correct?

Let $V,W$ be vector spaces and suppose ${v_1,v_2,\dots ,v_n}$ is a basis for $V$. Then, for $w_1,w_2,\dots ,w_n$ in $W$, there exists a unique linear transformation $T:V\to W$ such that $T(v_i)=W_i$, for $i=1,2,\dots ,n$

@Roma_Rayado $$U(w_j)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} B_{ij}v_i, \text{for} j=1,2,\dots ,n$$ .I think this is the correct formula.

Let $T:\Bbb R^2\rightarrow\Bbb R^2$ be a linear transformation s.t. $T(e_1)=2e_1$,$T(e_2)=e_1+e_2$,where $e_1=(1,0)$, and $e_2=(0,1)$.So $T$ can be uniquely extended from $\Bbb R^2$ to  $\Bbb R^2$.Clearly $T$ is invertible (as $e_1$ and $e_1+e_2$ are linearly independent so rank$(T)=2$ and nullity$(T)=0$)Further let $\beta=\gamma=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$.Then, $$[T]^{\beta}_{\beta}=\begin{bmatrix}
2&1\\
0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$Clearly $[T]^{\beta}_{\beta}$  is invertible and inverse of $[T]^{\beta}_{\beta}$ is $$\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}&\frac{-1}{2}\\
0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$Now define, $T^{-1}(e_1)=\frac{1}{2}e_1$ and  $T^{-1}(e_2)=\frac{-1}{2}e_1+e_2$.Then, $[T^{-1}]^{\beta}_{\beta}=([T]^{\beta}_{\beta})^{-1}.$ But if you define,Case-$1$:$T^{-1}(e_1)=e_1$ and  $T^{-1}(e_2)=e_2$ then matrix representation of $T$ is the Identity matrix of order $2$,which is not the inverse of $[T]^{\beta}_{\beta}$.Case$2$:If you define $T^{-1}(e_1)=e_2$ and  $T^{-1}(e_2)=e_1$ ,then again matrix representation of $T^{-1}$ is not the inverse of $[T]^{\beta}_{\beta}$.
So nutsshell of the above discussion is that by defining $U(w_j)=v_j$ (in your case) matrix representation of $U$ need not be equal to  $[T^{-1}]^{\beta}_{\gamma}.$Edit:As you already know the theorem that "if $\beta=\{w_1,w_2,....,w_n\}$ is a basis of $W$ and $U$ is a linear transformation from $W$ to $V$ defined by $U(w_j)=v_j$ for some $v_j\in V$ and $j=1,2...,n$, then $U$ can be uniquely extended from $W$ to $V$".So because of this unique extention you can not find the same linear transformation by defining the images of $w_i$'s under $U$ to the elements of $V$ other than $v_i$'s.
